# How do I install ATI Radeon HD 3200 graphics driver in 12.04 64 desktop?

Tags: ati, graphics, fglrx

I have had difficulty installing the drivers and I'm open to running a newer version of Ubuntu.  To get the ATI Radeon™ HD 3200 graphics working on an acer 5517 is there a way to do it that is reliable?

I have tried some PPA installs and had to reinstall Ubuntu, not a crisis but is there a way to get the drivers installed?

Is there a reliable way to install fglrx

This didn't seem to work
[Old Fglrx Driver - AMD Radeon HD 3200 - ubuntu won't start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223775/old-fglrx-driver-amd-radeon-hd-3200-ubuntu-wont-start)

Answer (score 1):

You have a quite old card. If you go to the AMD page and go through the choices, you land here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64

In the bottom, you have:

> Description: Automated installer and Display Drivers for Xorg 6.9 to
>   Xserver 1.12 and Kernel version up to 3.4

So, if you want to use the proprietary AMD drivers, you have to stay with a (very old) version of the kernel and X stack. Chances are that you have a newer kernel (try with `uname -a`) and X stack (`dpkg -l xserver-xorg`); fglrx drivers **do not** support this configuration. So you have two possibilities:

1. use the open-source drivers (should work reasonably well; supported by Ubuntu; this is my personal preference)
2. downgrade kernel and X stack (but here you'll be on your own --- and will come the time when there will be no security support for that).

Note that this situation come from an AMD decision --- the drivers are their and they decide what to do; probably supporting legacy drivers with newer kernels has become too expensive for them.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, if you google ubuntu help you get information that is (well intentioned) and at one time accurate, and now essentially outdated.  I still prefer Ubuntu on the acer 5517 and get allot more performance out of the system than running any other OS.  I was really looking for a confirmation that the backward support from ATI is not offered and that using the default drivers in the Ubuntu install the best choice.

Comment: @CharlesDaringer yes --- your comment is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the AMD web site:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx
and manually download.

To install the package type "sudo sh ./ati-driver-installer-x86.x86_64.run" in terminal

Comment: It works only if he has a quite old kernel and X stack. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you two are confirming that allot of the old suggestions and PPA links simply no longer work.